# Angular Date filter is not working in Firefox, but fine in Chrome

Tags: angularjs

In firefox-I got null value

In Chrome -it works perfectly.Using this following code.

```
var date = $filter('date')(new Date(value.Date), userData.datePattern);
```

How do I get it to work in Firefox?

Comment: is value.Date a string?

Comment: Please provide us detail info. e.g-> firefox version, chrome version, actual code etc.

Comment: firefox version,-38.0

Answer (score 1):

Date is implementation dependant across browsers, as such it doesn't work consistently in many aspects. It's for this very reason that most of the AngularJS community prefers to use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), and effort was made early by the AngularJS team to keep it compatible. Most find it simple to use.

Along with this, I recommend standardizing your Date serialized format as ISO8601. You'll find it to be the most compatible across languages and platforms currently.

Comment: What I'm trying to explain is that Date is poorly written across browsers. Using Moment instead of new Date() might help cure that for you.